Set Customer Header in WebView2
I am on Delphi 11.2 (28.0.46141.0937). I have installed Microsoft Edge Webview2-Runtime 125.0.2535.92. I use the WebView2Loader.dll version 1.0.2478.35.
I try to set two headers for a request

User-Agent
Authorization

I got the User-Agent working according to How to set useragent in new Delphi TEdgeBrowser?
I also tried the Custom header for Authorization with Edit HTTP Request header with WebView2 or set Webview2 header or cookie
Neither of them works for Authorization.
The BrowserWebResourceRequested is never triggered, a break point is not reached. The BrowserNavigationStarting has no effect, it seems.
procedure TURLAnzeigenF.BrowserCreateWebViewCompleted(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; AResult: HRESULT);
var
  debug: HRESULT;
  settings2: ICoreWebView2Settings2;
  useragent: string;
begin
  inherited;    
  OleCheck(Sender.SettingsInterface.QueryInterface(IID_ICoreWebView2Settings2, settings2));
  if Assigned(settings2) then begin
    useragent := 'Custom ' + GetMyVersion;
    OleCheck(settings2.Set_UserAgent(PChar(useragent)));
  end;
  debug := Sender.DefaultInterface.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter('*', COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT_ALL);
  OleCheck(debug);
  Blubb;
end;

procedure TURLAnzeigenF.BrowserWebResourceRequested(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; Args: TWebResourceRequestedEventArgs);
var
  temprequest: TWebResourceRequestedEventArgs;
  request: ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequest;
  headers: ICoreWebView2HttpRequestHeaders;
  token: string;
begin
  if (optionaltoken <> '') then begin
    temprequest := TWebResourceRequestedEventArgs(Args.ArgsInterface);
    try      
      token :=  'Bearer ' + optionaltoken;
      //OleCheck(Args.ArgsInterface.Get_Request(request));
      OleCheck(temprequest.ArgsInterface.Get_Request(request));
      OleCheck(request.Get_Headers(headers));
      OleCheck(headers.SetHeader('Authorization', PChar(token)));
    finally
      temprequest.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TURLAnzeigenF.BrowserNavigationStarting(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; Args: TNavigationStartingEventArgs);
var
  token: string;
  headers: ICoreWebView2HttpRequestHeaders;
begin
  inherited;
  if (optionaltoken <> '') then begin
    token :=  'Bearer ' + optionaltoken;
    Args.ArgsInterface.Get_RequestHeaders(headers);
    OleCheck(headers.SetHeader('Authorization', PChar(token)))
  end;
end;

The dfm-part:
  object Browser: TEdgeBrowser [2]
    Left = 0
    Top = 93
    Width = 630
    Height = 353
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 2
    UserDataFolder = '%LOCALAPPDATA%\bds.exe.WebView2'
    OnCreateWebViewCompleted = BrowserCreateWebViewCompleted
    OnNavigationStarting = BrowserNavigationStarting
    OnWebResourceRequested = BrowserWebResourceRequested
  end

Fiddler

Are there any obvious mistakes that I don't see?
